# linux fail2ban not catching auth a specific fail with postfix

Tags: python, regex, fail2ban

I had journalctl open and noticed an offender repeatedly hitting me with auth fails in postfix.  I have a standard postfix-sasl filter on by default that, to my knowledge, is working well.

It wasn't catching this one offender, of course my curiosity kicked it as to why.  So I compared a legit postfix ban with this particular entry and notice only that LOGIN was not in upper case.

legit ban = `Jul 03 11:47:30 domain.ca postfix/smtpd[9298]: warning: unknown[87.120.84.169]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure`

no catch = `Jul 03 11:50:15 domain.ca postfix/smtpd[9554]: warning: unknown[190.119.186.242]: SASL login authentication failed: authentication failure`

So I went into my filter `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix-sasl.conf`

added this:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [ A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2})?\s*$
                ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:login|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [ A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2})?\s*$
```

from this:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [ A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2})?\s*$
```

All I did was change the **LOGIN** to **login** and it caught this particular offender.

Since I suck at python regex, and I didn't find an easy doc.  How would I go about to simply add one line that will catch upper and lower case for these entry variables `(?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5)` ?

ps
Since this is postfix generating the log, why would it be that it entered a LOGIN for one log, and login for another...  different type or method of auth failed and the author wrote the entry of different caps for each maybe?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about to simply add one line that will catch upper and lower case ...

It is even possible completely case insensitive.
This is if your fail2ban uses python3 (mostly the case nowadays) - this switches case sensitivity for a local part in parenthesis.

```
- (?:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5)
+ (?i:LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5)
```

Or to make the whole RE case insensitive (or for python2), simply add global flag `(?i)` to start of RE:

```
- ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: ...
+ (?i)^%(__prefix_line)swarning: ...
```

> Since this is postfix generating the log, why would it be that it entered a LOGIN for one log, and login for another...

It's hard to say without to inspect the whole source code around that log-entry.
This can be simply original foreign data, supplied in the request from the client, in that case `lOgIn` or `PlAiN` would be theoretically possible too, because according to RFC 5321 SMTP command verbs are not case sensitive (no idea what exactly is allowed by postfix).